# Change CSS color property dynamically on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function that generates random colors, I want to use that function in conjunction with jQuery's ability to `toggleClass` on click. I want to generate a unique color to a `table` cell on click, and to remove the generated color if user clicks on a colored cell again (make it white again/colorless).

HTML table:

```
   <div id="container">
        <table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Color generation function:

```
    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
```

Assigning the color to the cell:

```
$( function(){
    $('td').click( function(){
            $(this).css('background-color',getRandomColor);
    });
});
```

Comment: so whats the question, is your code working?

Comment: Half working. It adds random colors, but the color is not changed to white once I click an already colored cell.

Comment: Please note: the accepted answer only works on a subset of browsers. Have added a more portable alternative below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note solutions using `'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'` only work on some browsers (Chrome, but not IE for instance). This version gets the colour from the body for reference (but any element with no `background-colour` set will do.

You can change your code to a jQuery extension, called say `toggleRandomColor` like this:

```
var blankColor = $('body').css('background-color');
$.fn.toggleRandomColor = function () {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == blankColor) {
        $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor);
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-color', '');
    }
};
```

and then simply use it like this:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleRandomColor();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nmav8d3n/4/

Comment: Good answer, but what if all elements have colors? (a little bit extreme, but still a possible scenario, no?)

Comment: @undroid: the practical limit for list of anything in a browser is a few 100 before you need to change paging/display strategy. This method has no more overhead than having unique classes on elements but requires no authoring. We use this in production projects without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a class when you colour the cell, and check for it:

```
$('td').click( function(){

    var $td = $(this);

    if($td.hasClass('is-colour')) {
        $td.css('background-color','transparent')
            .removeClass('is-colour');
    else {
        $td.css('background-color',getRandomColor())
            .addClass('is-colour');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, probably didnt notice, but it works fine without those brackets too

Comment: @undroid Ah right, I have updated my answer to better solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understood you corectly, so you want to click on a cell and make it colored, if it is already colored make it white ?

if so

```
$( function(){
    var default_background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';

    $('td').click( function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            curr_background = $(this).css('background-color');

        if (curr_background === default_background){
            $this.css('background-color',getRandomColor);
        } else {
            $this.css('background-color', default_background);  
        }
    });
});
```

and here is fidle http://jsfiddle.net/qL10e5xd/

Comment: Note: This code will *not work* on any version of IE. Different browsers return different default values for `css('background-color')`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the default value and then generate new color, or remove that.

```
function getRandomColor() {
     var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
     var color = '#';
     for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
     }
     return color;
 }

$( function(){
    $('td').click( function(){
        if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
            // if background-color isn't set, jQuery returns 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
            $(this).css('background-color',getRandomColor);
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color','');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmav8d3n/

Comment: Why would i downvote this answer? exactly what i wanted. Thanks, works like a charm

Comment: @undroid: not you, somebody downvote that without explanation and I only want to know why :-)

Comment: Then yes, it would be interesting to know why was this downvoted.

Comment: Not my DV, but `'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'` only works on some browsers. it does not work in IE for instance as that returns a blank string. See my answer for a workaround (also converted it to a jQuery plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this code

```
$( function(){
    var clicked = flase;
    $('td').click( function(){
    if(!clicked){
            $(this).css({'background-color',getRandomColor});
            clicked = true;
    }
    else{
            $(this).css({'background-color','white'});
            clicked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Rezoyanul Islam Reza: This it not a *great* idea. This is a *really bad idea* that has been *serial upvoted!* Anything that introduces a scoped variable will not support multiple elements so should be discouraged. The state should come from the element itself (`class`/`data`/`attr`/`css` etc)

Comment: @Rezoyanul Islam Reza: Imagine my "surprise" when I found you work in the same city as Kamruzzaman. Also *not* surprised to find your own answers have also been serial upvoted recently too. Perhaps an email to addiesoft and iqrasys will slow down the cheating on SO? Not very professional behaviour :P